Enabling fork for a single private repo of an organization
I am part of an organization and we need to fork a single private repository.
In my repository settings i see the grayed out option to allow forking,

while in the organization settings i can enable forking.

The problem is that i want to enable fork only on that specific repository and enabling it at organization level will enable forking on every repository.
Is there a way to achieve that without having to cycle through a couple hundred repos to disable each one?
